# Rails 5 Params / Strong Params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a RESTful API (ActionController::API) service that accepts a list of params. The RESTful service takes a JSON body request (with Content-Type of application/json).  When I debug the controller/action (right after the action def) and take a peak at the params list, it appears as follows:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"given_name"=>"Mark", "subdomain"=>"development", "controller"=>"user", "action"=>"create", "user"=>{"given_name"=>"Mark"}} permitted: false>
```

**EDIT**
All the request has in it (when it is passed to the controller/action -- using POSTman):

```
{"given_name":"Mark"}
```

Notice that the object contains the given_name params twice.  Is this normal behavior?  I did not pass a "user" object (json object) to the controller/action?  What is the permitted flag?

When I try to use (right now I'm just testing RESTful call and assigning any values that the user object will except... no validations have been programmed yet):

```
user = User.new(params)
```

I get the error:

```
#<ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError>
```

So, I've looked everywhere for the reasoning behind this (why is there a "user" key in the params list? What is the purpose of the permitted flag? Why am I getting an error when I try to assign params)?

**EDIT**

After doing some testing, I change the controller name from "user_controller" to "tester_controller" and setup the routes to point to the renamed controller.

It seems the "user" object in the params list above has changed to "tester".  So why does the param list contain an "object" with all the passed params with the name of the controller?  If that's the case, why is it needed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should be `params['user']` no ? Like this it seems you are trying to assign attribute `controller` or `action` of user

Comment: All the request has in it when it passes it is:  {"given_name":"Mark"}.  But in the action, I get the Parameters listed above.

Comment: So, I renamed the controller to "tester_controller" from "user_controller".  It seems the "user"=>{"given_name":"Mark"}" has changed to "tester"=>{"given_name":"Mark"}".  Why is there an "object" with the controllers name added to the params list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which attributes are acceptable for mass-assignment in your controller.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:given_name))
end
```

This prevents malicious users from making request posts that alter attributes internal to your application, like `role` in the case of a user object.

As mentioned above, a better explanation can be found in the guide referring to [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Answer (score 3):

By default Rails in API mode wraps JSON request parameters into a hash guessing its name from controller class. That's why changing the controller from User to Tester changes "object" name. You can read details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

So if you don't need this "object" in your params just remove `:json` from `:format` array in `config\initializers\wrap_parameters.rb`. Or you can use fine-grained control at the controller level as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `params` to constructor, because `params` always contain `:action` and `:controller` keys. Attributes for new objects should be put in hash under key that identify model you want to create e.g. `:user`. I suggest you to consult [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org), especially [chapter 7](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions) of "Form Helpers" guide.

If you want to learn more about strong parameters there is a [chapter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) in rails guides for that too :)